# How do I 'turn off' a SVG animation if I'm in IE or Safari?

Tags: css, svg, css-animations

So currently I have an SVG which contains three dots and two lines coming off those dots at certain intervals thanks to CSS3 animations.

In Chrome they're working fine but IE just isn't playing ball. What I don't get is why aren't the lines showing on my example? And how do I get them to appear, even without animating in, i.e just static on page load in IE?

Fiddle here - https://jsfiddle.net/y2j8huto/1/

```css
/* Constellation line animations */

.path {
  stroke-dasharray: 1400;
  stroke-dashoffset: 1400;
  animation: dash 500ms linear forwards;
}

.path1 {
  stroke-dasharray: 1400;
  stroke-dashoffset: -1400;
}
.path2 {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 400ms; 
  animation-delay: 400ms;
  stroke-dasharray: 1400;
  stroke-dashoffset: -1400;
}

@keyframes dash {
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<!-- First constellation -->
<svg class="constellation_figure-one" viewBox="-2 -2  1000 650" version="1.1">

  <g id="Group" stroke="rgb(255,255,255)" stroke-width="1" fill="none">

    <!-- The apartment star -->
    <circle cx="50" cy="20" r="6" fill="black" />
    <line class="path path1" x1="250" y1="635" x2="50" y2="20" stroke="black"  />

    <!-- The building star -->
    <circle cx="250" cy="635" r="6" fill="black" />
    <line class="path path2" x1="827" y1="327" x2="250" y2="635" stroke="black" />

    <!-- The amenities star -->
    <circle cx="827" cy="327" r="6" fill="black" />
  </g>

</svg>
<!-- First constellation -->
```

Comment: Which versions of IE and Safari did you test on when it didn't work? Are you talking IE8 or IE10?

Comment: I believe it was IE9. I ended up using snap.svg in the end. Was a lot easier and had cross-browser support.